# IOS. Understanding stack view

Tags: ios, swift

I am new. And I want to create a structure like this:

```
label (unknown size)  | View 
label (unknown size)  | View
```

My structure like this:

[image]

But the label is cut, How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: Make another screen-shot, but expand all of the `>` items so we can see your constraints.

Comment: Could it be that the green View on the left side has a height constraint or something?

Comment: You have to set the"Lines" property of the label to "0" for infinite lines. currently it looks like it is being set to "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you go for a hierarchy like the screenshot below. How you can do this is by changing your views as follows,

1. Change the axis of the parent `UIStackView` to **vertical**, and the 2 child `UIStackView` to **horizontal**. **Make sure the parent Stackview has no height set**
2. Make sure the distribution of the horizontal StackViews are `fill`
3. Add The labels into the horizontal StackView and set **ONLY** the width (ex- 250 in my example)
4. Then add the `UIView` into the horizontal stackview. It should fit in the rest of the StackViews space

Voila!

In the image below

- Blue, Purple are UIViews
- Red, Green are UIStackViews with background colors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for question. You should set Label’s line property to Zero 0 in attribute inspector. It should stop cutting text and will wrap it in new line.